# Iptables forwarding rules between two VLANs are not working

Tags: networking, iptables, vlan, forwarding

There has to be something I am missing.
I have two VLANs and want to allow inter-vlan communication for certain IPs and ports, basically I want to let 192.168.16.2 connect to 192.168.15.4:80 and allow all related&established traffic.
I have added logging rule and from what I see I do not understand what am I doing wrong, because it should have matched.
Everything else works very pretty, as machines from 99 can reach 3, but not vice versa, 192.168.16.3 can reach eth2 which is wlan. But rule this rule  `-A FORWARD -p tcp -i br-lan.3 -s 192.168.16.2 -d 192.168.5.4 -o br-lan.99 --dport 80` do not work. Also ICMP ping same destiny - dropped.

Perhaps you can spot error?

Router's `ip addr`

```
18: br-lan.99@br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XXXX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.15.1/24 brd 192.168.15.255 scope global br-lan.99
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd71:adef:67d:10::1/60 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::da58:d7ff:fe00:3b25/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: br-lan.3@br-lan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XXXX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.16.1/24 brd 192.168.16.255 scope global br-lan.3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd71:adef:67d::1/60 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::da58:d7ff:fe00:3b25/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`iptables -L -nv` for FORWARD:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 60 packets, 4785 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   96  5004 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
 457K  447M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   19  1012 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan.99 br-lan.3  192.168.15.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
  617  165K ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan.99 *       192.168.15.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan.3 br-lan.3  192.168.16.2         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan.3 *       192.168.16.1         0.0.0.0/0  
   10   760 ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan.3 eth2    192.168.16.3         0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  br-lan.3 br-lan.99  192.168.16.2         192.168.5.4          
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br-lan.3 br-lan.99  192.168.16.2         192.168.5.4          tcp dpt:80 
   71  5409 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "FORWARD-DROP:"
```

Command used to setup iptables:

```
 -P FORWARD DROP
 -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
 -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -i br-lan.99 -s 192.168.15.0/24 -o br-lan.3 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -i br-lan.99 -s 192.168.15.0/24 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -i br-lan.3 -s 192.168.16.2 -o br-lan.3 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -i br-lan.3 -s 192.168.16.1 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -i br-lan.3 -s 192.168.16.3 -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -p icmp -i br-lan.3 -s 192.168.16.2 -d 192.168.5.4 -o br-lan.99 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -p tcp -i br-lan.3 -s 192.168.16.2 -d 192.168.5.4 -o br-lan.99 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
 -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD-DROP:"
```

Here is a produced log `tail -f /var/log/messages | grep "FORWARD-DROP"`:

```
Dec 21 18:50:29 XXXX kernel: [  709.598723] FORWARD-DROP:IN=br-lan.3 OUT=br-lan.99 MAC=XXXX SRC=192.168.16.2 DST=192.168.15.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64367 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34270 DPT=80 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec 21 18:50:30 XXXX kernel: [  710.599559] FORWARD-DROP:IN=br-lan.3 OUT=br-lan.99 MAC=XXXX SRC=192.168.16.2 DST=192.168.15.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64368 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34270 DPT=80 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec 21 18:50:32 XXXX kernel: [  712.619432] FORWARD-DROP:IN=br-lan.3 OUT=br-lan.99 MAC=XXXX SRC=192.168.16.2 DST=192.168.15.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=64369 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34270 DPT=80 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec 21 19:16:15 XXXX kernel: [ 2255.472602] FORWARD-DROP:IN=br-lan.3 OUT=br-lan.99 MAC=XXXX  SRC=192.168.16.2 DST=192.168.15.4 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=16847 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=6879 SEQ=0
Dec 21 19:16:25 XXXX kernel: [ 2265.383554] FORWARD-DROP:IN=br-lan.3 OUT=br-lan.99 MAC=XXXX  SRC=192.168.16.2 DST=192.168.15.4 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=19255 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=6886 SEQ=0
```

Comment: Please replace the `iptables -L -nv` output with `iptables-save` output.

Comment: @TomYan I have added it.

Comment: You have two rules that have the destination IP being `192.168.5.4` instead of `192.168.15.4`.

Comment: @TomYan Ok, I am just so blind and I was like checking it at least 20 times. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @TomYan feel free to add it as answer, so you can get your bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a typo in the rules that `192.168.15.4` became `192.168.5.4`.